# What is the correct statistical test to compare data points from a time series

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have the following dataset, comprising of two variables - condition (either recession or normal) and unemployment (a number).

[image]

I need to test if the unemployment rate is higher during a recession. What is the right statistical test for me to use please? I think it is ANOVA but wanted to check.

Comment: If your research question is simply whether unemployment is higher during a recession or during normal periods of economic growth, a Welch’s t-test will be fine.

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a 
photograph or screenshot (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). 
When you retype the question, add the [tag:self-study] tag 
& read [its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've 
tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help 
you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.